flutter extracting int from a list and processing it into time format
I have a list containing a number of information, including a duration in second. I want to extract the duration into 3 integers: "hours", "minutes" and "seconds".
this is the list:
class historique extends StatelessWidget {
  historique({super.key});
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> courses = [
    {
      "name": "Course 1",
      "date": "20/03/2024",
      //"logo": "course1",
      "distance": 12967,
      "temps" : 7384
    },
    {
      "name": "Course 2",
      "date": "06/03/2024",
     // "logo": "course2",
      "distance" : 17413,
      "temps" : 13854
    },
    {
      "name": "Course 3",
      "date": "27/02/2024",
   //   "logo": "course3",
      "distance" : 4967,
      "temps" : 3891
    },
  ];

This is what I tried
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var course = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments  as Map<String,dynamic>;

    int hours = (${course['temps'];}) /3600;
    int minutes = ( (${course['temps'];}) - (hours*3600) ) /60;
    int seconds = (${course['temps'];}) - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

The error code near the $ tells me that $ is an undefined name so I'm guessing there's an issue with the syntax.

Your using string interpolation on an expression which is not correct.and only use semicolon ; on the end of the line .
What do i mean by that look here for example
int hours = (${course['temps'];}) /3600;

Which it should just be
int hours = course['temps'] /3600;

as for the rest of the code here is the copy and paste to fix the mentioned issue
int hours = course['temps'] / 3600;
int minutes = course['temps'] - (hours*3600) ) /60;
int seconds = course['temps'] - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

